# Is it possible to create a matrix visualization in power-bi similar to the pic that I have attached?

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I would like to create a matrix visualization or custom visual that looks exactly like this:
[image]

Note that the current challenge is that the last two columns that is, "Current state weighted average score" and "Future state weighted average score" are only for domain and not for subdomain. So, that is why they are to be displayed only once(For each domain).

Is it possible to create something exactly like this in Power-BI?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can do that but it needs a bit things to be modified on Field formating.
You can create something like this.
Please check the below image which I have created something like that.

[image: View the image reference]

Follow the steps.
In my case, I have the fields as below

[image: See the image]

1. Enable the row subtotals under the subtotals in format pane.

[image: View the image for reference]

2. Go to field formatting and choose the "Current state weighted average score" column. In my case it is "value2" column.

[image: See the image]

3. Change only the font colour to "red" that would match the colour on the table(under the same field formatting option)
4. And enable only to values as below image.

[image: See the image]

Hope your problem should be resolved with this

Comment: Thank you very much for your time guys. I was able to use your solution with some minor changes. Cheers :)

Comment: No Problem ..Cheers :)